# RandomAccessFile java malformed input

Tags: java, input, randomaccessfile, malformed

I'm working with binary files, and I'm trying to write and read from them, I have these two functions :

```
 public static void ListToBin (List<ModelVehicle> llModVeh,List<Vehicle> llVeh,String NomFitxerXml){


         try {
             File ff = new File("pruebas.bin");
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(ff, "rw");
        int q = llModVeh.size();
        raf.writeInt(q);
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            for(ModelVehicle m : llModVeh){
                raf.writeChars(m.getNom() );
                raf.writeChars(m.getMarca());
                raf.writeShort(m.getCilindrada());
            }
        }
        raf.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
 }
```

and :

```
 public static void BinToList(List<ModelVehicle> llModVeh,List<Vehicle> llVeh,String NomFitxerXml){
     try {
         llModVeh =new ArrayList();
         File ff = new File("pruebas.bin");
         RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(ff, "r");
         int q = raf.readInt();
         if (q < 0) {
             throw new RuntimeException("Fitxer corrupte");
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
             String nom = raf.readUTF();
             String marca = raf.readUTF();
             Short cilindrada = raf.readShort();


         }
         raf.close();
     } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }


 }
```

When i use the function ListToBin to write  everything goes ok, but when i call the function BinToList i keep getting the error:

> java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 41
>
> at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:634)    at
>   java.io.RandomAccessFile.readUTF(RandomAccessFile.java:965)   at
>   info.infomila.Utils.BinToList(Utils.java:299)     at
>   info.infomila.Prova.main(Prova.java:84)

getMarca and getNom returns a string, getCilindrada a short!

Comment: an addition to the already given answer: in the ListToBin function you write the **entire** list as often, as the string is long, since you got a for loop with the list size and another for-each loop inside that. it does not cause the issue, but still is unnecessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing with `writeChars()` which writes exactly 2 bytes for each character. But you read with `readUTF()` which reads 1 or more bytes per character (depending on the character).

Either use `writeChars()` and `readChars()`, or `writeUTF()` and `readUTF()`.